# OpenCV: how to read an image of floats

Tags: c++, opencv, io, mat

I have created a Mat in openCV as follows:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(10,10, CV_32FC1);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        m.at<float>(i,j) = 1;
     }
}
```

and saving it to disk by:

```
imwrite("out.png", m);
```

I am now trying to read it as follows:

```
cv::Mat m = imread("out.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

but the data in m seems to be completely random, when accessed like `m.at<float>(5,5)` for example.

How can I read back in the data that is written to it? For example, in matlab I can do:

```
m = imread("out.png")
```

and it gives me the correct matrix of 1's

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

See [`imwrite`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imwrite)

> The function imwrite saves the image to the specified file. The image format is chosen based on the filename extension (see imread() for the list of extensions). **Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel** or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) **images can be saved using this function.** If the format, depth or channel order is different, **use Mat::convertTo() , and cvtColor() to convert it before saving.** Or, use the universal XML I/O functions to save the image to XML or YAML format.

[depth](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cv_16u#int%20depth), [convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const)